# How does the modulus shorten a number to only 16 digits in this example?

Tags: math, cryptography, solidity

I am learning Solidity by following various tutorials online.  One of these tutorials is Cryptozombies.  In this tutorial we create a zombie that has "dna" (a number).  These numbers must be only 16 digits long to work with the code.  We do this by defining

```
uint dnaDigits = 16;
uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;
```

At some point in the lesson, we define a function that generates "random" dna by passing a string to the keccak256 hash function.

```
function _generateRandomDna(string memory _str) private view returns (uint) {
    uint rand = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_str)));
    return rand % dnaModulus;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how the output of keccak256 % 10^16 is always a 16 digit integer.  I guess part of the problem is that I don't exactly understand what keccak256 outputs.  What I (think) I know is that it outputs a 256 bit number.  I bit is either 0 or 1, so there are 2^256 possible outputs from this function?
If you need more information please let me know.  I think included everything relevant from the code.

Comment: `rand` is a `uint`. So no matter what it contains, `rand % (10 ^ 16)` will have at most 16 digits. Which part of this is unclear?

Comment: @Beta you helped me realize where I went astray. I thought it was supposed to produce a number that is exactly 16 digits long, not at most 16 digits. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_str))` returns, it converted into `uint` because of the casting `uint(...)`.

```
uint rand = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_str)));
```

When it's an uint then the simple math, because it's modulus.

```
xxxxx % 100 always < 100
```

Comment: Thank you. Your comment also helped me arrive at the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I see now that this code is mean to produce a number that has no more than 16 digits, not exactly 16 digits.

Take x % 10^16

If x < 10^16, then then the remainder is x, and x is by definition less than 10^16, which is the smallest possible number with 17 digits I.e. every number less than 10^16 has 16 or fewer digits.

If x = 10^16, then remainder is 0 which has fewer than 16 digits.

If x > 10^16, then either 10^16 goes into x fully or not. If it does fully, remainder is zero which has less than 16 digits, if it goes in partially, then remainder is only a part of 10^16 which will always have 16 or fewer digits.

Comment: Please do not add additional information that should be in the answer as a comment. That forces anyone trying to answer, or find a solution, to read every comment and piece together their order. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment for more information. Instead, remove the comment and add it to your answer as if it'd been there initially. Don't add "edited" or "updated" type tags as we can see what has been changed.

Comment: Also, read "[answer]" and its linked pages. Your answer isn't a good example and probably should be a PS to your question or removed entirely.

Comment: Is my answer incorrect or just a bad example?  I can make it a PS to better illustrate how I am seeing the problem.

Comment: I am only concerned about the use of an answer for what appears to be a comment, which is not what answers are for. The [tour], [ask], [answer] and their links explain that.